# Kali linux: На wifi адаптере не работает airmon-gn

Tags: linux, wifi, драйвер, kali-linux, wireless

У меня 'Tp-link archer t4u wireless-ac1200 t4u' и когда я его подключаю к кали линукс(не виртуальная машина) скачиваю дрова, пробовал разные, выдает ошибку:

```
PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy1    wlan0       ??????       
cat: /sys/class/ieee80211/phy1/device/net/wlan0mon/type: No such file or directory

Newly created monitor mode interface wlan0mon is *NOT* in monitor mode.
Removing non-monitor wlan0mon interface...

WARNING: unable to start monitor mode, please run "airmon-ng check kill"
```

Как я понимаю дело в драйверах, может у кого была такая же проблема и он ее решил?

Comment: `airmon-ng check kill` пробовали делать?

Comment: @Alexshev92 В первую очередь

Comment: @Log1c0 что дает **ip address; lspci | grep -i wireless**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было скачать другой адаптер, https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au, всем спасибо!